# javascript pseudo classical inheritance and prototypal inheritance example confusion

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I did not really understand difference between pseudo classical & Prototypal Inheritance. Have a look at below code snippet.

Prototypal : I am able to understand this code (Douglas Crockford). I have 
changed the class names & added implementation for better understanding since his code blocks are incomplete in presentaiton.

```
var baseObject = {
    a : "old",
    firstMethod: function () {alert("First method");},
    secondMethod: function () {alert("Second method");}
};
var derivedObject = Object(baseObject);
alert(derivedObject.a);

derivedObject.thirdMethod = function () {alert("Third method");};
var derivedChildObject = Object(derivedObject);

derivedChildObject.firstMethod();
derivedChildObject.secondMethod();
derivedChildObject.thirdMethod();
```

Pseudo classical:

Since I did not get clarity from same code snippet in his presentation as methods are incomplete, I went to some other link in internet

http://javascript.info/tutorial/pseudo-classical-pattern

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Animal.prototype = {
  canWalk: true,
  sit: function() {
    this.canWalk = false
    alert(this.name + ' sits down.')
  }
}

var animal = new Animal('Pet') // (1)

alert(animal.canWalk) // true

animal.sit()             // (2)

alert(animal.canWalk) // false
```

The scheme for a pseudo-class:

Methods and default properties are in prototype.
Methods in prototype use this, which is the current object because the value of this only depend on the calling context, so animal.sit() would set this to animal.

Can you help me in providing right example?  You can take - Either Animal use case Or baseObject use case for reference Or come up with your own example

Comment: The second example "pseudo-classical" doesn't include inheritance. Inheritance would still be prototypal ...

Comment: It would be great if you provide example for pseudo-classical with simple example

Comment: @devnull69 just to clarify: did you mean that in javascript, all inheritance is protoptypal ?

Comment: @user2808054 correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the `canwalk` property on the object prototype  level that's why at the time when you instantiate the object you get `true` on alerting `(animal.canWalk)`. The reason why on the second alert you got `false` is that meantime you call the sit function where you set `canWalk` as false.

That's why is not too good practice to follow strictly the prototypal inheritance pattern:  typically, instances want to have their own copies of all properties. This is why the prototype pattern is rarely used on its own.

The most recommended is to use the **Parasitic Combination Inheritance**:

Combination inheritance is the most often-used pattern for inheritance in JavaScript, though it is not without its inefficiencies. The most inefficient part of the pattern is that the supertype constructor is always called twice: once to create the subtype’s prototype, and once inside the subtype constructor.

Essentially, the subtype prototype ends up with all of the instance properties of a supertype object, only to have it overwritten when the subtype constructor executes.

```
function SuperType(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
}

SuperType.prototype.sayName = function(){
    alert(this.name);
};

function SubType(name, age){
    SuperType.call(this, name); //second call to SuperType()

    this.age = age;
}

SubType.prototype = new SuperType(); //first call to SuperType()
SubType.prototype.constructor = SubType;
SubType.prototype.sayAge = function(){
    alert(this.age);
};
```

To overcome that supertype constructor is always called twice we can tweak this by using the following trick: instead of calling the supertype constructor to assign the subtype’s prototype, all we need is a copy of the supertype’s prototype:

```
function inheritPrototype(subType, superType){
    var prototype = object(superType.prototype); //create object
    prototype.constructor = subType; //augment object
    subType.prototype = prototype; //assign object
}
```

Then we can replace:

```
SubType.prototype = new SuperType(); //first call to SuperType()
SubType.prototype.constructor = SubType;
```

with

```
inheritPrototype(SubType, SuperType);
```

**Pseudo classical inheritance:**

Using this pattern you define the properties on object level and the methods on object's prototype level:

```
function SuperType(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
}

SuperType.prototype = {
    constructor: SuperType,
    sayName : function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
```

If you don't point the constructor to the `SuperType` when you instantiate the object calling `instanceof` still returns true for both `Object` and `SuperType`, but the constructor property is now equal to `Object` instead of `SuperType`.

```
var superType = new SuperType();
alert(superType instanceof Object); //true
alert(superType instanceof SuperType); //true
alert(superType.constructor == Person); //false
alert(superType.constructor == SuperType); //true
```

An example for inheritance:

```
function SuperType() {
    this.property = true;
}

SuperType.prototype.getSuperValue = function() {
    return this.property;
};

function SubType() {
    this.subproperty = false;
}

//inherit from SuperType
SubType.prototype = new SuperType();

SubType.prototype.getSubValue = function () {
    return this.subproperty;
};

//override existing method
SubType.prototype.getSuperValue = function () {
    return false;
};
```

Here are two very strong reference about inheritances in Javascript:

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/
http://www.allitebooks.com/professional-javascript-for-web-developers-3rd-edition/

Comment: Thank you very much. I am clear on prototypal inheritance especially on constructor part. Can you please provide example for pseudo classical too?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example for prototypal inheritance

```
var Mammal = function() {
   this.isMammal = true;
};

var Cat = function() {
   this.meow = function() {
      alert('Cat says: MEOW!');
   };
};

Cat.prototype = new Mammal();
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

var kitty = new Cat();
if(kitty.isMammal) {...}       // evaluates to true
kitty.meow();
```

Prototypal inheritance is accomplished by reassigning the prototype to an instance of the base class. This will lead to a prototype chain always ending in Object.prototype

If you're looking for a method or member, you start with the instance, then you go down the prototype chain until you find the method/member (or you don't).

Example for toString() and kitty from our example:

```
kitty.toString();

1. kitty instance doesn't have toString() method
2. Cat.prototype doesn't have toString() method
3. Mammal.prototype doesn't have toString() method
4. Object.prototype has toString() method, which will be called in the context of kitty
```

Comment: What is the significance of below line in your example? Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

Comment: Because by reassigning the prototype you also reassign the constructor to `Mammal`. So if you still want `Cat()` to be the constructor function for cats, you need to re-reassign it

Comment: Thank you very much. I am clear on prototypal inheritance. Can you please provide example for pseudo classical too?

Comment: Even if you call it "pseudo classical" ... it is still prototypal, even though you try to hide it by using different method calls. There is only one type of inheritance in Javascript and it is prototypal

Comment: One last question. The ppt of Douglas Crockford says:                         Three mechanisms of Pseudoclassical:

    1) Constructor functions.

    2) The new operator.

    3) The prototype member of functions.   After reading this slide, I thought that prototype member functions are part of prototypal inheritance & pseudo classical inheritance is super set of prototypal + first two features - Constructor & New features. If we have only prototypal inheritance, does it imply that all three features he quoted are part of prototypal inheritance?

Comment: @sunrise76 yes it does. You can use prototypal inheritance without new and even without constructor functions, but even when you use those features, the result will still be prototypal

Comment: I think this question should be protected as it provides good insight into prototypal inheritance. I do not know the mechanism to categorize this question as protected as I am new to the site.